# Referencing in-page SVG in Chrome

Tags: css, html, svg

Interesting question for someone. I'm trying to apply an SVG filter to an image loaded in the page using the following markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  #exampleImage { 
    filter: url("#grayscale");
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <img id="exampleImage" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/Bitmap_VS_SVG.svg/300px-Bitmap_VS_SVG.svg.png" />
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <filter id="grayscale">
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"/>
    </filter>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine in Firefox - the image appears grayscale - but not in webkit (Chrome or Safari on Mac). From what I've been reading, this should work. Can you see anything I'm missing?

Thanks!

- Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your example made in a way that works in all browsers that support svg filters:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  #exampleImage { 
    filter: url("#grayscale");
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <filter id="grayscale" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"/>
    </filter>
    <image id="exampleImage" xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/Bitmap_VS_SVG.svg/300px-Bitmap_VS_SVG.svg.png" width="100%" height="100%"/>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Safari started supporting filters in version 6, see [table of support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-filters) for all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, turns out the filter: url() syntax isn't webkit-friendly, despite what I'd read elsewhere.

Instead, for this particular scenario you need to use the CSS rule:

-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);