# One filter for few separate inline svg graphics

Tags: html, css, svg, inline-code

My plan is:

-to use multiple *inline SVG* icons in HTML5 markup - this way:

```
<ul>
<li><svg>content</svg></li>
<li><svg>content</svg></li>
...
<ul>
```

-apply to each graphic a SVG filter (bit complicated *inset shadow*).

In addition, I want to avoid declaring filter in each *inline svg* (or even BODY section). Yes, I can save *filter* code in separate SVG file and apply filter in CSS:

```
svg {filter: url(filter.svg#inset-shadow);}
```

but it doesn't work in webkit. So I have to bring back my *filter* into html and change its size to min 1px according to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13695176/referencing-in-page-svg-in-chrome,) 
My questions:

1. **Can I declare `<SVG>SVG filter</SVG>` in the HEAD section of HTML document?**
2. **Are there any other solutions in described scenario?**

Comment: Did you find the answer? I'm in a similar situation, and would love to do this.